# App Randomly Closes during Navigation Drawer Open on specific device

Tags: android

During Navigation Drawer slide in and out the app randomly closes on the specific device (Sony Z - model C6606 (KitKat)) but on others doesn't seem to happen.

Could you suggest some troubleshooting ideas for this issue? The device is with a client and cannot be hooked up to ADB.
Ideally I would like to be able to pinpoint the issue whether it's with the device or my application.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a crash on a device that you can't access to hook up to ADB, you may want to look into a way to receive reports on crashes. I recommend [Crashlytics](http://www.crashlytics.com) -- it can e-mail you alerts when your app crashes along with a stacktrace that you can use to pinpoint where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Could try installing an uncaughtExceptionHandler:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)